# Set.constructor`alert\x28document.domain\x29``` meaning

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was learning about XSS and I came across this syntax which works in browser. Can anyone tell me why is it executing in detail.

````
Set.constructor`alert\x28document.domain\x29```
````

Comment: It's using a tagged template literal to invoke the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's interesting. We've got

````
 Set.constructor`alert(...)```
````

Let's consider this part first:

```
Set.constructor`alert(...)`
```

is a [tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates), and is equivalent to the following function call (provided there are no `${...}` placeholders within backticks):

```
 Set.constructor(['alert(...)'])
```

`Set` is a class, which is a function in JS, therefore `Set.constructor` is `Function`, that is, the above is the same as

```
 Function(['alert(...)'])
```

or, since `Function` converts it arguments to strings,

```
 Function('alert(...)')
```

which dynamically creates a function from the given textual content.

Now, we have two more backticks, so that our overall expression becomes:

```
Function('alert(...)')``
```

which is again a tagged literal and equivalent to a function call

```
Function('alert(...)')([''])
```

which invokes our newly created function with a rubbish argument.

In other words, this is a creative way to `eval` things.

Comment: At what step does it trigger the alert?

Comment: @royatirek: ah, I didn't notice there are two more of them... edited.

Comment: Hey georg after I have two more doubts - 1. First Let A {
    constructor(abc){
    this.abc = abc;
    }}  and running this A.constructor('alert("Hi")') shows ƒ anonymous(
) {
alert("Hi")
} in console. Why does it does not show complete variable initialisation. Why is it calling alert

Comment: 2. Running A.constructor()('alert("Hi")')  does not work but running A.constructor('alert("Hi")')()  works but we are doing just the same thing in both cases according to me.

Comment: @royatirek: interesting questions, but a bit hard to answer in comments. Care to post a new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667282/why-does-javascript-constructor-prints-the-argument-passed-to-it, this is the question