# Why does javascript constructor prints the argument passed to it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanted to know the internal working of the constructor in javascript.
So here is what I am facing- 
Let us assume a class A

```
class A {
constructor(){}
}
```

Now when I run the the command in console

```
A.constructor('alert("Hi")')
```

This commands prints

```
ƒ anonymous() {
 alert("Hi")
 }
```

Why does it not show complete initialisation or am I missing something?

This leads alert to execute when we run

```
A.constructor('alert("Hi")')()
```

Though running this

```
A.constructor()('alert("Hi")')
```

does not execute the alert.

I am totally confused and hence want to know how constructor interpret things.

Comment: Note that `A.constructor === Function.prototype.constructor`

Comment: Can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1.

```
A.constructor('alert("Hi")')
```

Since `A` is a class (=a function), `A.constructor` is the built-in `Function` constructor, and this code is the same as

```
Function('alert("Hi")')
```

or

```
function () { alert("Hi") }
```

that is, an anonymous function with the body `alert("Hi")`. The console displays exactly that.

#### 2.

```
A.constructor('alert("Hi")')()
```

is the same as

```
Function('alert("Hi")')()
```

or

```
( function() { alert("Hi") } ) ()
```

that is, the newly created function is being called and displays an alert.

#### 3.

```
 A.constructor()('alert("Hi")')
```

`A.constructor` is `Function`, and `Function()` creates an anonymous function with no body, so we have:

```
 ( function() {} ) ('alert("Hi")')
```

The function is being called with an argument `alert("Hi")`, but since is has no body, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `A.constructor()`, you are not actually calling the constructor of class A that you defined in class A, you are accessing the [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) of A. What Object.prototype.constructor does? It returns the reference to the constructor which was used to create A.

As A is a class and class is a function in javascript, `A.constructor` returns reference to `Function` i.e. So `A.constructor` is equivalent to `Function`.

As `Function("alert('hi')")` in javascript is equivalent to `ƒ anonymous( ) { alert('hi') }`, `A.construtor("alert('hi')")` is equivalent to `ƒ anonymous( ) { alert('hi') }`.

So it means `A.construtor("alert('hi')")` returns a reference to function i.e. `ƒ anonymous( ) { alert('hi') }`, so that answers **1st** part of your question.

Now how do you call function in javascript? You use the parenthesis after the function reference. As `A.constructor("alert('hi')")` returns function reference, you can call that function using `A.constructor("alert('hi')")()` which executes the alert. That answers the **2nd** part of your question.

In the third part i.e. `A.constructor()('alert("Hi")')`, first, `A.constructor()` returns `ƒ anonymous( ) {}`, which you are calling providing parenthesis in front if it i.e. `('alert("Hi")'` but as this function is empty, nothing happens while calling it. So that answers the **3rd** part of your question.

Hope it clarifies the confusion.